# Proof for the product of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Taking for example *2 x 2 x 2 ...*, I know that we can represent this as *r = 2r*, which should result to be *r = 0*.

Now my question arises when attempting to prove whether the (k+1)<sup>th</sup> element is greater than the k<sup>th</sup> element, i.e.

*2<sup>k+1</sup> = 2<sup>k</sup> x 2*, which should suggest *2<sup>k+1</sup> > 2<sup>k</sup>*, thus by induction the product should continuously increase by a product of 2, i.e. r > 2, but how is the result *r = 0* justified?

Comment: The product $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \ldots$ is divergent. The reasoning that results in $r = 2r$ assumes the product converges to $r$, which in this case, it does not.

Comment: @Shreyas what are you asking exactly?

Comment: You've proved that if it converges, then it converges to $0$.  Since it doesn't converge to $0$, it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

> Taking for example 2 x 2 x 2 ..., I know that we can represent this as r = 2r, which should result to be r = 0.

Only if the product actually converges. For a sequence of numbers $a_n$, we say

$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_n \text{ converges if and only if } \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n a_n \text{ exists}$$

Moreover, the value attributed to the infinite product is given by that limit if it exists.

Let $a_n = 2$ for all positive integers $n$. Then $\prod_{i=1}^n a_n = 2^n$. Obviously, this diverges as $n \to \infty$, and thus so does the infinite product. However, if $a_n = 1/2$ for example, then you can show the infinite product is zero.

Clearly, the claim $r=0$ is totally unjustified in this light. Such operations are not always justified.